# Non-standard back button in Action Bar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, back-button, navigation-drawer

I've seen in several apps a non-standard back button ([image #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xlQX.png)) in the action bar,

Normally when I config a navigation drawer or the setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled it just looks like [image #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8jzO.png)

How can i accomplish the non-standard style?

Comment: It looks like the standard home button to me.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a back button. It is sometimes called a "hamburger icon", and it is specifically used for indicating the presence of `DrawerLayout` navigation. You can find more information in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html). You can see more about the icon's functionality [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html).

Comment: I'm not reffeering to the tree lines of the navigation drawer, I'm talking about the button contains text and is larger that the standar back button

Comment: [Other example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/581pV.jpg") of the non-standar back button

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I believe this is the standard behavior of the back button + Action Bar title on Android 4.2 and above. Try checking it out on a 4.2 device or emulator to see what I mean. Unfortunately, I don't know how to emulate that behavior in previous versions of Android.

Comment: My phone is running 4.1.2 and I'm getting apps like facebook messenger with the back button extended with the action bar title